# Merging and inheriting parameters

Tags: saxon, xslt-grouping, xslt-3.0

Using xslt version 3.0 (saxon):

I have something like the following

```
<root>
  <template ID='1'>
    <params>
      <a>1</a>
      <b>1</b>
    </params>
  </template>

  <document1 templateID='1'>
    <params>
      <b>4</b>
      <c>5</c>
    </params>
  </document1>

</root>
```

Basicly I need to convert into something like

```
  <root>
    <document1 templateID='1'>
      <params>
        <a>1</a>
        <b>4</b>
        <c>5</c>
      </params>
    </document1>
  </root>
```

In the example parameter `a` is inherited from the template while parameter `b` is overwritten by the document itself and parameter `c` is not known or set in the template. It is akin to inheritance or how css work. I hope you get the idea. Before starting the task I thought this should not be too difficult (and still hoping Im just overlooking something).

I have tried something with concat'ing the two nodeset (using `nodeset1 , nodeset2` to preserve the order) and using a preceding-sibling name based 'select'/'filtering' - but this strategy seems not to work as it seems they are not actual siblings. Could this be done with a clever group-by ? Can it be done at all ? (I think it can)

I am using xslt version 3.0 (saxon)

Comment: The code samples you have posted, are these XML samples? Or is that meant to be some XSLT pseudo code? It is kind of confusing in the world of XSLT to ask for merging parameters and talk aboute templates given that these terms are used in the XSLT language itself. If the first is simply an XML input sample and the second the XML result sample you want to create with XSLT, what determines the order of child elements (i.e. `a`, `b`, `c`) of the `params` element in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to group or merge, merging in XSLT 3 would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:key name="template-by-id" match="template" use="@ID"/>

  <xsl:template match="template"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[@templateID]/params">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:merge>
              <xsl:merge-source name="template" select="key('template-by-id', ../@templateID)/params/*">
                  <xsl:merge-key select="string(node-name())"/>
              </xsl:merge-source>
              <xsl:merge-source name="doc" select="*">
                  <xsl:merge-key select="string(node-name())"/>
              </xsl:merge-source>
              <xsl:merge-action>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="(current-merge-group('doc'), current-merge-group('template'))[1]"/>
              </xsl:merge-action>
          </xsl:merge>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rN8/

grouping would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:key name="template-by-id" match="template" use="@ID"/>

  <xsl:template match="template"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[@templateID]/params">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="key('template-by-id', ../@templateID)/params/*, *" group-by="node-name()">
              <xsl:copy-of select="head((current-group()[2], .))"/>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rN8/1

I think, as `xsl:merge` requires input to be sorted on any merge key or to sort the input first, the grouping above is easier and more reliable, unless your `params` child elements are really named with sorted letters or words from the alphabet.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responce. The input (the params) is not supposed to be sorted and may come in random order(if thats what you mean). The `template` could also come after the `document`, however that would be easier to arrange to make sure it always comes first. So the `group-by` sounds promising and thinking it could work - will test it next week.